# How to get option value using $_GET and fancybox?

Tags: php, html, get, fancybox

In my html page

```
$(function(){
    $('.addallitem ').fancybox({
        openEffect : 'elastic',
        closeEffect : 'elastic'
    });
});
```

**HTML**

```
    <select class="category">
            <option value="All">All</option>
            <option value="Apparel">Apparel</option>
            <option value="Appliances">Appliances</option>
    </select>
    <a href="addallitem.php?category=" class="addallitem fancybox.ajax">Add All</a>
```

I got confused what should i put in the `addallitem.php?category=` ?

When I click the add all there will be a pop up form and the form should receive the option value

Thanks for those who help :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### What kind of HTML is this?

```
<a href="addallitem.php?category=" class="addallitem fancybox.ajax">Add All</button>
```

It starts with `<a>` and ends with `</button>`!

If you want to do a `$_GET` request, the best way is:

```
<button onclick="location.href='addallitem.php?category=' + $('.category').val()" class="addallitem fancybox.ajax">Add All</button>
```

I still don't understand, why you need a class like `fancybox.ajax`. And let us know more on what you wanna achieve and full JavaScript code, if you have any.

Comment: fancybox.ajax is just from the fancybox api to have stylish pop up form thats all

Comment: hmm it work but my form does not pop out and it change the entire page :(

Comment: Do you get any errors in the page? What browser are you using?

Comment: not not anymore and i properly retrieve the value but the display is the problem it does not pop up anymore and it replace the entire main page,

Comment: Any live page or script having public access?

Comment: no live page, just created it locally

Comment: ow it works now! i just removed the location.href, make it to href=..etc